# When to use Application.targetFrameRate in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new to game development and targeting mobile platforms. I don't know why and when we should use the Application.targetFrameRate to limit frame rate.

Comment: are you thinking of limiting frame rate to help with performance on low end devices?

Comment: yeah, I'm thinking whether limiting frame rate have any good impacts on performance?

Comment: I read somewhere it could benefit performance because your CPU will have more idle time between frames to do stuff. But don't know where I read it though.

Answer (score 3):

Use Application.targetFramerate when you want to limit its cpu/gpu use. By default it might eat up all the available cycles and try to push some ridiculous rates like 300fps. I often limit framerate to as low as 20 (below it stops being responsive) if I make i.e. an utility application (yes unity is not just for games) that I want to run alongside other applications and I don't want it behaving like a spoiled child and taking all the power to itself.

I also often use a very low limit like 1fps wen my app is not in the foreground to stop it from rendering even further.

As far as improving performance on a mobile device - this is not the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Create a game object in the first scene and attach a script named **GameManager** or what ever name you give. Then in Awake function use **Application.targetFrameRate**, and also create a static instance of this class and also use **DontDestroyOnLoad** for this game object.

Comment: No, that is not what I means. I means that whether limiting frame rate have any impacts on low end devices like mobile.

Comment: how the f is this answer related to the question

Comment: This was my reading of the question too, and this answer gave me what I was looking for, so thanks Rasel.

Comment: The answer helped me